# Why are ogr2ogr SQLite geometry functions not available in command line?

Tags: gdal, spatialite, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I believe title is all clear.I'm using Ogr2ogr utilities & binaries to read geometry.
I used something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" test2.sqlite test.sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_X(GEOMETRY),ST_Y(GEOMETRY),COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE"
```

Error says that there is no function ST_X,where I also tried X(..) that doesnt work either.
What am I missing ?

I checked the [documentation](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html#p5) for SpatialLite.There is no other inline function that export X,Y portions of geometry to double.I also need to create geometry from LAT,LONG columns from selection.

How can i do these ?

Comment: Is it possible that your OGR was built without spatialite support? It is not enabled by default. You can check with something like "ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" test.sqlite test1.sqlite -sql "SELECT sqlite_version()" (which should always work as long as test1.sqlite exists and test.sqlite doesn't), then try ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" test.sqlite test1.sqlite -sql "SELECT spatialite_version()"

Comment: I can confirm BradHards - the spatialite extensions in the sqlite driver are optional.

Comment: @BradHards I use the latest binaries for OGR utilities.I believe OGR has support for it.By the way,your query works as i verified it with ogrinfo tool.

Comment: Where did you get the binaries? There are multiple sources, none of which are really "official". Can you amend the question to show the results of each ogrinfo test? I'm particularly looking for the line that starts with spatialite_version() (String) =

Comment: I get the binaries from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/.I found the solution,the sqlite file did not built with spatiallite option which in creation should use -dsco spatialite=yes.SQLite support SpatialLite functions that's true only if spatialite option is enabled..

Comment: Myra: can you turn your solution into an answer (below) and mark it as done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution as for source table did not created with spatialite option which default is false.

To do that simply add parameter to ogr2ogr utility `-dsco "SPATIALITE=YES"` then all SpatialLite parameters shall work as requested.

Answer (score 6):

Also, in order to use spatialite style queries, you must specify

```
-dialect sqlite
```

in ogr2ogr and ogrinfo sql

Comment: here is an example how to do this for select by location https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270044/42932

Answer (score 1):

Check that your version of ogr is built with sqlite *and* spatialite support.

http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html - section "Spatialite SQL functions"

Comment: As I confirmed with @BradHards comment,ogr is built with such support.But the functionality I wish to use is the same in your documentation link that doesn't work ! What is missing here ?

Comment: link is broken, please update