# select by location using ogr2ogr sqlite

Tags: gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I have a shapefile containing polygons and a shapefile containing points. Now I would like to select the polygons that contain points.

How can I do this from the command line using `ogr2ogr`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the following link all SQL functions that test spatial relationships are described:
http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/spatialite-sql-2.4.html#p12.

The following spatial relationships can be used within a query

`ST_Equals` - `ST_Disjoint` - `ST_Touches` - `ST_Within` - `ST_Overlaps` - `ST_Crosses` - `ST_Intersects` - `ST_Contains` - `ST_Relate`

For this type of request you can do this using the `ST_Containts` query of `sqlite`. 
Which can be adopted in a `ogr2ogr` command as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" selection_polygon.shp shapefile_polygon.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT polygon.Geometry, polygon.id FROM shapefile_polygon polygon, 'shapefile_point.shp'.shapefile_point point WHERE ST_Contains(polygon.geometry, point.geometry) GROUP BY polygon.id"
```

Example

Picture of `shapefile_polygon.shp` and `shapefile_point.shp`:
[image]
And picture of **`selection_polygon.shp`** and `shapefile_point.shp`:
[image]

Expanded options of the spatial relationships:

- `ST_Equals` Returns true if the interior and the boundary of the two geometries are spatially equal
- `ST_Disjoint` Returns true if the boundaries and interior do not intersect
- `ST_Touches` Returns true if the boundaries intersect but the interiors do not
- `ST_Within` Returns true if the interior of the given geometry does not intersect with the exterior of another geometry
- `ST_Overlaps` Returns true if the interiors of two geometries have non-empty intersection
- `ST_Crosses` Returns true if the interiors of the geometries intersect but the boundaries do not
- `ST_Intersects` Returns true if the interiors of the geometries intersect
- `ST_Contains` Tests if the given geometry contains another geometry
- `ST_Relate` Returns true if this geometry is spatially related to another geometry